# How to get Country of flickr images using flickr.photos.search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr

I have the following URL:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&license=1,2,4,7&has_geo=1&extras=original_format,description,date_taken,geo,date_upload,owner_name,place_url,tags&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=c55f5a419863413f77af53764f86bd66

And it's returning some geolocation info such as latitude, longitude, place_id and woeid. But it doesn't send country directly.

Though I can get the country by reverse geocoding it's lat, long. But in that case, it needs a separate API, network call for each and every image which is I don't want to do.

So is there any way by which I can get the country from the above API call(or modified)